# Flutter POST request body is empty on server side

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var post = jsonEncode({
    "coach_id":id,
    "date":_value ,
    "user_id":userId ,
    "timeslots":duration ,
});

print(post);

var response = await http.post(url,headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}, body: post);


if (response.statusCode == 200) {


var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
print(responseJson);

  return response;
} else {
  return null;
}
  } catch (exception) {

    print('exception---- $exception');
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: What is the output of `print(post);` ? Did you try setting hard-coded values in the JSON and check at the server end ?

Comment: output of the post is {court_id: 2, date: 2020-05-21, user_id: 7, timeslots: [3, 4]}

Comment: and the server response is like {response_code: 0, message: Enter Data, status: failure}

Comment: The output looks more of a Map than a JSON string. Try providing a hard-coded data first and then the actual values. 'll post the answer.

Comment: i already tryed but i getting same response nothing change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've done request using postman and understood that server accepts: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.

So correct way doing postman request is:

[image: 1]

and correct code is:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
```

```dart
try {
  final headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  };

  final form = [];
  form.add("coach_id=$id");
  form.add("date=$_value");
  form.add("user_id=$userId");
  for (var value in duration) {
    form.add("timeslots[]=$value");
  }
  final body = form.join('&');

  final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
  return null;
}
catch (exception) {
  print(exception.error);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214477/discussion-on-answer-by-num8er-flutter-post-request-body-is-empty-on-server-side).

Comment: Plz note that the "content-type" in the headers may also translate the request body sent into a different data type on server side! See this answer for clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599552/14335655

Answer (score 0):

The output you see looks more of a Map than the JSON string. You might want to try setting up the hard-coded data first just to check everything is okay from the server end.

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    "coach_id":id,
    "date":_value ,
    "user_id":userId ,
    "timeslots":duration
  };


HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(url));

request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
request.headers.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(data))); 
// utf8 is optional but a good idea so as to handle the different chars

HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

String serverResponse = await utf8.decoder.bind(response).join();
print(serverResponse);
```

Comment: i tried before this and after your suggestion i tried this again but im getting same response  {response_code: 0, message: Enter Data, status: failure}

Comment: The code looks alright. Do you have server documentation and/or sample request ? If we are sending integer instead of string or with an incorrect parameter name e.g. user_id instead of userId then the server wouldn't get the expected value and return an error.

Comment: I tried to call the API via Postman and get same response (with code 0). This means there is no problem with the code. Either there is a problem in the server or it is not getting the data as expected. You better contact someone from the server side.